# Laravel: Form file uploads failing - incorrect type detected

Tags: php, html, laravel, file, safari

I have recently gone live with a system that uploads CV's and I am getting an unusually high number of rejections, approximately 15%.  When I look at the log it shows me the following results:

- The extension reported by the client is `docx` (based on `$file->getClientOriginalExtension()`)
- The MIME type reported by the client is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` (based on `$file->getClientMimeType()`)
- Laravel/PHP detects that the files are `.bin` (based on `$file->extension()`)

In other words, the client says it is uploading a docx file, but the server says it receives a bin.  At first I thought it was simply corruption, but it occurs far to often.

I have only captured a few in the logs so far, but I note that each time Safari has been the browser.  Are there any systemic issues with Safari?  If so, how do I get around them?

What else could cause the problem?

I am triggering the form submit with Vue, but I don't see how that could make a difference.  Here is the Vue code:

```
document.getElementById("new-application").submit();
```

Comment: If you taking it from request try this one $type = $request->file->extension();

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a Safari browser?

Comment: which headers are you sending with the post request ? issue can be related to headers also

Comment: since the `$file` from laravel's request, then it's an istance of `UploadedFile`.The best way to get the MimeType is from the header of file itself, try `$file->getMimeType()` (never trust client) can you post the result of the method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that PHP uses the `file` command from the OS (in this case Ubuntu) to guess the extension based on the contents of the file.  It was getting it wrong.  Upgrading Ubuntu would probably help.

Comment: on ubuntu it's easy to download and compile and install the latest version of file yourself, install it to /usr/local/bin, you can find the source of the latest version here ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/  (latest version as of writing: 5.37) - it's basically just `sudo apt install gcc; wget ; cd ;./configure; make ; sudo make install`

Answer (score 3):

`docx` is Microsoft Word Open XML Format Document, a XML-based and all the content is stored as separate files, and ultimately compacted in a single, ZIP-compressed file. It seems like a file container.

And we should not take file extension as same with mimetype. As far as know a normal ( A mp4 file with docx should not take as normal ) file with `docx` file extension can has one of these mimetypes.

```
'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
'application/zip'
'application/CDFV2'
```

In your code,

`$file->getClientOriginalExtension()` extract extension from the original file name that was uploaded which should not be considered as a safe value.

`$file->getClientMimeType()` extract the mime type from client request which should not be considered as a safe value.

Both these two functin implemented in `./vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/UploadedFile.php`

Then take a look at last function in your code,

`$file->extension()` use some method to ***guess (which maybe not accurate)*** the file extension. In sequence php's `finfo` ([manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)) which base on the file content, the system `file`. As the below source code it's guess, so it's not accurate all the time. Refer to [file command apparently returning wrong MIME type](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185216/183001).

***Here you should get it***. If you want to go further, see below source code of the function `extension`.

---

**Source Code**
`extension` call `guessExtension` to guess the file extension, and `guessExtension` use the mimetype returned by `guessMiMeType`

```
// FileHelpers.php
public function extension()
{
    return $this->guessExtension();
}
```

```
// File.php
public function guessExtension()
{
    return MimeTypes::getDefault()->getExtensions($this->getMimeType())[0] ?? null;
}
...
public function getMimeType()
{
    return MimeTypes::getDefault()->guessMimeType($this->getPathname());
}
```

`guessMiMeType` use two guesser to guess the mimetype. php's `finfo` and system's `file`, and `finfo` take high priority than `file`.

```
//MimeTypes.php
public function __construct(array $map = [])
{
    foreach ($map as $mimeType => $extensions) {
        $this->extensions[$mimeType] = $extensions;

        foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
            $this->mimeTypes[$extension] = $mimeType;
        }
    }
    $this->registerGuesser(new FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser());
    $this->registerGuesser(new FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser());
}
...
/**
* Registers a MIME type guesser.
*
* The last registered guesser has precedence over the other ones.
*/
public function registerGuesser(MimeTypeGuesserInterface $guesser)
{
    array_unshift($this->guessers, $guesser);
}
...
public function guessMimeType(string $path): ?string
{
    foreach ($this->guessers as $guesser) {
        if (!$guesser->isGuesserSupported()) {
            continue;
        }

        if (null !== $mimeType = $guesser->guessMimeType($path)) {
            return $mimeType;
        }
    }

    if (!$this->isGuesserSupported()) {
        throw new LogicException('Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enable the php_fileinfo extension?).');
    }

    return null;
}
```

```
//FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php
public function guessMimeType(string $path): ?string
{
    if (!is_file($path) || !is_readable($path)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The "%s" file does not exist or is not readable.', $path));
    }

    if (!$this->isGuesserSupported()) {
        throw new LogicException(sprintf('The "%s" guesser is not supported.', __CLASS__));
    }

    if (false === $finfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, $this->magicFile)) {
        return null;
    }

    return $finfo->file($path);
}
```

```
//FileBianryMimeTypeGuesser.php
public function __construct(string $cmd = 'file -b --mime %s 2>/dev/null')
{
    $this->cmd = $cmd;
}
    public function guessMimeType(string $path): ?string
{
    if (!is_file($path) || !is_readable($path)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The "%s" file does not exist or is not readable.', $path));
    }

    if (!$this->isGuesserSupported()) {
        throw new LogicException(sprintf('The "%s" guesser is not supported.', __CLASS__));
    }

    ob_start();

    // need to use --mime instead of -i. see #6641
    passthru(sprintf($this->cmd, escapeshellarg($path)), $return);
    if ($return > 0) {
        ob_end_clean();

        return null;
    }

    $type = trim(ob_get_clean());

    if (!preg_match('#^([a-z0-9\-]+/[a-z0-9\-\.]+)#i', $type, $match)) {
        // it's not a type, but an error message
        return null;
    }

    return $match[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Safari is known for it's mime types, that are not correct. I'm sure in your case, it isn't sending docx mime like it should, but instead it is saying it is `octet-stream`. Well, your only workaround is(if your file is not corrupted) to manually set extension of file to correct one or manually send file from browser, making sure the mime is correct.